# Server is working but not showing anything With React, Node And Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, babeljs

The index.html works but when I try to run `app.jsx` code it does not show anything.

Server.js page

```
var express = require('express');
server.js page
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

var listen = app.listen(4040, function() {


 console.log('Express server is up on port 4040');
});
```

index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-faux-dom/3.1.0/ReactFauxDOM.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>  /*If something wrong with babel script *\

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  /*<h1>This text would display on server</h1>*\
  <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.jsx-page

```
var Greeter = React.createClass({ /*This jsx code wont deploy on server*\
  render: function() {            /*Maybe there is an error*\
    return (
      name: 'React',
      message: 'This is the default message!'
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    var name = this.props.name;
    var message = this.props.message;

    return ()

  }
      <div>
        <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
        <p>{message + "!!"}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var firstName = "Andrew";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeter name={firstName}/>,
  docucument.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: The Server suppose to output: Hello Andrew! This is the default messaage.

Comment: What url have you tried?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your app.jsx file. You have two render functions, which does not return anything sensible, and you have jsx code just suddenly outside of anything. You should probably try to follow along with a tutorial to get you set up.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest in your comment, Are you trying to set default props value or something?. Your app.jsx should look like.

```
var Greeter = React.createClass({ 
render: function() {        

var name = this.props.name;
var message = this.props.message;

return (
    <div>
     <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
     <p>{message + "!!"}</p>
   </div>  
  );
 };
});

var firstName = "Andrew";
var message = "This is the default message!";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeter name={firstName} message = {message}/>,
 docucument.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: when I put: localhost: 4040 the page uploads empty.

Comment: I tried different ports: localhost:6000, 8000, 4040 it still would not upload anything even after changes with app.jsx. The page is just blank.

Comment: This what shows me inside the  Developers tool chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:5000/app.jsx:  Unexpected token (13:2)
   </div>
  );
 };
});

var firstName = "Andrew";
    at t.o.raise (browser.min.js:27)
    at t.u.unexpected (browser.min.js:28)
    at t.u.expect (browser.min.js:28)
    at t.u.parseObj (browser.min.js:27)
    at t.u.parseExprAtom (browser.min.js:27)
    at t.parseExprAtom (browser.min.js:29)
    at t.u.parseExprSubscripts (browser.min.js:27)